# Unexpected gap between two columns

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react application and one of the pages has a two column layout. When I'm using a larger screen, there is a gap in between the two columns, thats not there on a smaller screen like a laptop. When i use the chrome inspect tool on the larger screen, the gap disappears.

I know its not my CSS doing this because I've adjusted every margin and padding value and it still shows up. I've even tried the resolution and the display on the larger screen and its still there.

[image: Unexpected column gap]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

ProjectList.js

```css
.project-list-page {
    float: right;
    width: 90vw;
}

.project-top-bar {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}

.project-top-bar input {
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    border: none;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    width: 25vw;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.project-list {
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.project-column {
    float: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 87vh;
}

.project-left-side {
    width: 30%;
}

.project-right-side {
    width: 70%;
}

.project-list-item {
    padding: 2em 0.5rem;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.project-list-item:hover {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.project-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<>
  <div className='project-list-page'>
      <div className='project-top-bar'>
          <input type="text" className='project-search-input' placeholder='Search projects ...' />
          <button className='btn new-project-btn'>New Project</button>
      </div>
      <div className='project-column project-left-side'>
          <ul className='project-list'>
              {projectList.map(project => {
                  return <ProjectListItem project={project}/>
              })}
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div className='project-column project-right-side'>
          Preview
      </div>
  </div>
</>
```

ProjectListItem.js

```html
<Link to={`/projects/${project.name}`}>
    <li className='project-list-item'>
        {project.name}
    </li>
</Link>
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducable code example?

Comment: Could be padding, margin, a scroll box, a flex/grid gap, and others. Could you share with us some code (mainly HTML and CSS)?

Comment: I just added it